# Error in crontab

Tags: cron, debian

I'm putting the following instructions:

```
00 12 * * * /usr/bin/php -q -f
* * * * * * /var/www/html/glpi/scripts/ldap_mass_sync.php action=1
* * * * * * ldapservers_id=1
```

But I'm getting the message:

```
crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.6N2VjD/crontab":1: bad command
errors in crontab file, can't install.
Do you want to retry the same edit? (y/n)
```

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
00 12 * * * /usr/bin/php -q -f
* * * * * /var/www/html/glpi/scripts/ldap_mass_sync.php action=1
* * * * * ldapservers_id=1
```

should be fine

only 5 stars are allowed

Comment: Do u think that's correct form of execute these commands? I'm doing a LDAP sync

Answer (score 3):

Cron follows following format.

```
<Minute> <Hour> <Day_of_the_Month> <Month_of_the_Year> <Day_of_the_Week>
```

You are using extra `*` and it doesn't follow format. You need to remove extra `*`.